# SharePoint Security Group Membership based on SharePoint Profile Property

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online

Is it possible to add people to a SharePoint security group on a site collection using a SharePoint profile property?

For example I have John who is a people manager and I have a custom profile property "peopleManager" set to true for John in SharePoint properties, and want him to be added automatically to a security group "XYZ" on Site Collection "ABC"

Answer (score 0):

Well I created a dynamic office 365 group in Azure AD with a rule set on "peopleManager" property which adds users to the group automatically and then set the permissions in target site collection by giving permissions to this group.

This has solved the problem.